# grab text by pattern with start and end tag in multiple lines

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I want to grab multiple lines in a file with a pattern that has a starting and an ending tag in an ungreedy way.

For example I have the following input:

**file.txt**

```
START
test1
test2
foo
END
some
more text

START
test3
bar
test4
test5
END
even more

START
baz
test6
END
```

Now I want to look for **bar** and print out everything between **START** and **END**, so that I will get:

```
START
test3
bar
test4
test5
END
```

What I have so far is the following grep command:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)START.*?bar.*?END' file.txt
```

The problem is, that this expression is greedy and prints out:

```
START      # starts at first "START"-tag, not the next one
test1      #
test2      #
foo        #
END        #
some       #
more text  #

START
test3
bar
test4
test5
END
```

It's not done with the grep flags **--before-context** / **--after-context**, because the count of lines before and after can differ.

The tool used by text-processing doesn't matter. It should work on a general RedHat system. Also the faster the tool grabs the lines, the better it will be. Because I have big logfiles of each about 150MB.

Can someone tell me, how to achieve my goal the best way?

---

### Update:

Okay, I got it. I just had to think about how to construct my command from `don_crissti`s link. Here's the solution:

```
ed -s file.txt <<< $'g/bar/?START?,/END/p\nq\n'
```

Thank you very much for all your very fast help!

And yes, finally it's a duplicate...

Comment: Do you want to allow for multiple lines within the START and END? It is not entirely clear from your examples as they are all single lines, but you state _everything between START and END_

Comment: @DanSut The line count before and after can be different. I updated my examples so that it's more clear.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for showing up this question. Finally, this solved my problem!

Comment: Is it really a duplicate if you specifically asked about `grep`? which you did ;)

Comment: I mean... I needed **one** solution and started doing this with `grep`. Since it's regardless which program I'll use, `awk` and `ed`/`sed` are good enough, too ;) But also I'm looking for the fastest command (which I didn't state before), because I have to lookup in files of about 150 MB (logfile). So, all solutions (grep, ed, awk) are working. Now, which one is the fastest way in an objective view?

Comment: @bobbel glad your got your solution and personally didn't have any real restrictions, but [thinking more long term someone may be searching that does have your restrictions, or is just interested in how grep -P or pcregrep can be made to do this... so does it really help to mark as a duplicate?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3677/133470)

Comment: @DanSut I see what you're about to clarify. So, strictly speaking: I'm not aware of the tool used by text-processing for my problem. I also changed the title of my question to satisfy this. Furthermore I added more specific text due to get the fastest solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that your non-greedy matches can still swallow up more than you want them to, ie. *END*s and *START*s.  This seems to work:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)START(?:(?!END).)*?bar(?:(?!START).)*?END' file.txt
```

It covers all cases in your example and to be complete if you `>> file.txt`

```
bar
START
test7
END
```

Still works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This also works for my specific problem!

Answer (score 2):

I would use awk, where you can specify the record separator. If the record separator is "END" (on its own line), then look for the record containing "bar":

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = ORS = "\nEND\n"} /bar/' file.txt
```

---

Handling text that appears between the START and END markers. This change feels hacky, but it works for this scenario: using END as the record separator, remove any text before the START keyword

```
awk '
    BEGIN {RS = ORS = "\nEND\n"} 
    {sub(/^.*\nSTART\n/, "START\n")} 
    /bar/
' file.txt
```

This may not give desired results if "START" can appear more than once before END

```
foo
START
hello
START
bar
world
END
baz
```

will output as

```
START
bar
world
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm not sure how to match from the START tag on. Between END and START tag there could also be some more unimportant lines that I don't want to match. I've put it in my example what I mean.

Comment: Now it works like a charm for my problem! Thank you very much, too!

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN {$/="\nEND\n"} say /(START.*test.*)/s'
```

As @bobbel point out, replace `say` by `print` to avoid empty line separators.

Comment: I tried with `perl -nE 'BEGIN {$/="\nEND\n"} say /(START.*bar.*)/s' file.txt` and got also some new lines after the match. I added a `| grep -v ^$` to the end and this solved the problem, too.

Comment: Also I did a benchmark of all four solutions (grep, awk, ed, perl) and the perl solution is much faster than all other solutions. Thank you very much!

Comment: I replaced `say` with `print` to prevent printing out empty new lines. Now it's perfect: `perl -nE 'BEGIN {$/="\nEND\n"} print /(START.*bar.*)/s' file.txt`